# How to Make Cyberduck Open Directly into an FTP Server

Tags: macos, ftp

I recently setup an FTP server and would like Cyberduck to open it directly when it opens. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to *Preferences → General* and select *Open new browser window on startup*. Just below select the bookmark you want to connect to on startup from the *Connect to bookmark* drop down list.

Comment: Kudos to that one, i've been using my method. This should be the best answer, not mine.

Answer (score 1):

Go into the directory you wish to open automatically and press Shift-Cmd-B.